# app recently published "has stopped"

Tags: android, google-play, publish, publishing

I recently published my app on Google Play, but when I install it and run it simply don't run and message me "app has stopped". On my device and emulator it runs normally, and I don't know what to do.

Anyone had this problem and can help me??!!

Comment: Have you tried installing local copy of obfuscated .APK on your device?

Comment: I installed from the PC, running on Eclipse. And it has no logcat, cause I it messages "has stopped" and stop after "ok".

Comment: if it's getting a force close, there will be a stack trace in the log. connect your real device and do an "adb logcat" then run your app to cause the crash.

Comment: Or, since it's through Google Play, look in the Developer Console under "Crashes/ANRs" or "Errors". Stack traces can be found there.

Comment: I transfer the .apk to my device and install from it, and the error occurs. But I still don't know what to do. =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Play asked me to change the package name, so I did. But I right clicked on project -> Android tools -> rename application package and it din't change all configurations and I had to chenge it manually.

After that it's work allright.